# using new keyword Ontrigger in unity warning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm Inheriting a parent class and I added new private void OnTriggerEnter2D on chid class and the parent class has a OnTriggerEnter2D method also but it says the new keyword is not required. I just wanted a clarification on this why the built in OnTriggerEnter2D doesn't need a new keyword.

Comment: It's unity magic :D. Basically the base method won't be called and doesn't exist if you don't define it in your class.

Comment: It's not a Unity magic...

Answer (score 0):

In C#, the `new` keyword is only needed when any parent of your class is using a member with the same name and signature, and you want to completely ignore the member in the parent class.

for example:

```
public class Parent
{
    public void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Message From Parent");
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public new void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Message From Child");
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void TestRunner()
    {
        Parent parent = new Child();
        parent.OnTriggerEnter(); // output Message From Child.
    }
}
```

This behaviour is exactly as if you override a virtual method without calling it's base.VirtualMethod.

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Message From Parent");
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public override void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        //base.OnTriggerEnter();
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Message From Child");
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void TestRunner()
    {
        Parent parent = new Child();
        parent.OnTriggerEnter(); // output Message From Child.
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup I have a same method name in my base class